# PHP's Infinit value in Bitwise Operations returns strange values

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

Today I just made an interesting discovery while testing what happens calculating bitwisely in php like `INF ^ 0` (`^` => Bitwise Operator for Exclusive OR (XOR)) what gave me `int(-9223372036854775808)` => greatest possible negative value in a 64-Bit system.

But then I was asking myself: "Why is the result going negative in XOR when the "positive infinit" means `9223372036854775807` (63 Bits on `1` with a leading `0`) and 0 (64 Bits on `0` => `0 xor 0 = 0`) What is PHP's infinit value though and what is the calculation behind it? And why do I get a (correct?) negative value when I use "negative infinit"(A leading `1` against a leading `0` on 0 => `1 xor 0 = 1`?".

Another interesting point is that this just happens on PHP Version 5.5.9-1, and not e.g. on 5.3.x. and 5.6.x (where i've tested it)! Maybe someone has an idea what happens there? Tested it on three versions but just mine (5.5.9-1) gives those results:

[image: Bitwise operations]

Just to let you guys know, it's just an abstract playaround i've done for fun but I find it's interesting. Maybe someone can help here or explain me a wrong thought I have? Just tell me if someone needs more informations about anything!

EDIT: Accordingly to jbafford it would be great to get a complete answere, so i'll just quote him: `why does 5.5 and 5.6 result in PHP_INT_MIN, and everything else return 0?`

Comment: `-9223372036854775808` is greatest possible negative value __for a (64-bit) integer__.... `INF` isn't an integer, but an [IEE754 float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985)

Comment: Do you think that the problem is probably in the bitwise comparision from `float(INF)` to `int(0)`? Do you know how this works?

Comment: You're using bitwise operations on a 64-bit float value, but using bitwise operations treats the value as though it was a 64-bit integer value `Bitwise operators allow evaluation and manipulation of specific bits within an __integer__.`..... therefore it's a fallacious comparison. The bitwise ops don't typecheck whether you're executing them against a float, because they're interested at the bit level, but they will set the resulting data type to an integer

Comment: Well that sounds pretty logical! But this still don't explains why the 64th bit will go to `1` if the float gets probably converted into an interger (it just seems like and i cannot find any example for comparing a float with an integer) or do I still missunderstand that?

Comment: I would post this as an answer but don't really have time to vet it properly: To me, it looks like with XOR you're setting all of the bits in INF that aren't in zero. XOR is adding an extra bit causing overflow. Overflow is system dependent but, you typically see values wrap from highest to lowest which would explain your result of `-9223372036854775808` as you're XORing all the bits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, `^` itself isn't what's special here. If you XOR anything with zero, or OR anything with zero, you just get back the original answer. What you're seeing here is not part of the operation itself, but rather what happens before the operation: the bitwise operators take integers, so PHP converts the float to an integer. It's in the float-to-integer conversion that the weird behaviour appears, and it's not exclusive to the bitwise operators. It also happens for `(int)`, for example.

Why does it produce these weird results? Simply because that's what the C code PHP is written in produces when converting a float to an integer. In the C standard, C's behaviour for float-to-integer conversions is *undefined* for the special values of `INF`, `-INF` and `NAN` (or, more accurately, for "integral parts" an integer can't represent: [§6.3.1.4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf#55)). This [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behaviour) means the compiler is free to do whatever it wants. It just so happens in this case that the code it generates produces the minimum integer value here, but there's no guarantee that will always happen, and it's not consistent across platforms or compilers.<sup>1</sup> Why did the behaviour change between 5.4 and 5.5? Because PHP's code for converting floats to integers [changed to always perform a modulo conversion](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/77566edbafb969e166239b3fbc929588c6630ee9). This fixed the undefined behaviour for very large floating-point numbers,<sup>2</sup> but it still didn't check for special values, so for that case it still produced undefined behaviour, just slightly different this time.

In PHP 7, I decided to clean up this part of PHP's behaviour with the [Integer Semantics RFC](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/integer_semantics), which makes PHP check for the special values (`INF`, `-INF` and `NAN`) and convert them consistently: they always convert to integer `0`. There's no longer undefined behaviour at work here.

---

<sup>1</sup> For example, a test program I wrote in C to try to convert Infinity to an integer (specifically a C `long`) has different results on 32-bit and 64-bit builds. The 64-bit build always produces `-9223372036854775808`, the minimum integer value, while the 32-bit build always produces `0`. This behaviour is the same for GCC and clang, so I guess they're both producing very similar machine code.

<sup>2</sup> If you tried to convert a float to an integer, and that float's value was too big to fit in an integer (e.g. `PHP_INT_MAX * 2`, or `PHP_INT_MIN * 2`), the result was undefined. PHP 5.5 makes the result consistent, though unintuitive (it acts if the float was converted to a very large integer, and the most significant bits were discarded).

Comment: That was the answere i was looking for! Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: I'm glad you liked it! (Though I don't really care for it, you might want to award the bounty.)

Answer (score 4):

Your `float(INF)` gets implicitly casted to an Integer.

and XOR with 0 does not change the first parameter. So basically this is just a cast from float to int which is undefined for values which are not in the integer range. (for all other values it will be truncated towards zero)

https://3v4l.org/52bA5

Comment: This does not actually answer the more interesting part of the question, which is, why does 5.5 and 5.6 result in PHP_INT_MIN, and everything else return 0?

Comment: possibly because that's what the underlying C function returns. But since the result is undefined it could be any arbitrary number and it would still be a "correct" result

Comment: Well, yes, of course. But an interesting answer would be *what specifically* changed (and why) in 5.5 and 7.

Comment: @jbafford My answer might go somewhere towards that.